# Recreating this image of an atomic set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

On slide 24 of [this talk](http://people.lids.mit.edu/pari/atomic_norm_talk.pdf) one finds this image

[image]

which is supposed to depict the atomic set e^{i \phi} [ 1, e^{2 pi i f}, e^{4 pi i f}, ... e^{2 (n - 1) pi i f}]^T for phi in [0, 2 pi) and f in [0, 1).
I am suspecting that only the real parts of the first three components of the vector is plotted for different phi values but that is not quite it.

I would be grateful if someone could identify what exactly is plotted and how to achieve the colouring on the surface.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[grid = major, view={-30}{30}]
        \addplot3[variable=t,samples = 60,domain=0:1]
        ({cos(2 * pi * deg(t))},{cos(4 * pi * deg(t))}, {cos(6 * pi * deg(t))});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what you said: take the real part of the first three coordinates, take the convex hull, triangulation, and plot. The problem is we do not know phi, the phase. Other than that, latex cannot do triangulation. It is fairly easy to plot the skeleton, though.

Comment: For the convex hull and triangulation, I'd say that must be some external program. Once you have the mesh, pgfplots can do the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Symbol 1 said, It seems that the plot corresponds to the real part of three successive elements + the convex hull.

I've tried it in Matlab and the closest graph corresponds to `[cos(2*pi*f+phi),cos(4*pi*f+phi),cos(6*pi*f+phi)]` and `phi=pi/2` and `f in [0,1]`

Here is the result:

[image]

This is generated by the following Matlab code:

```
f=0:0.01:1;
phi=pi/2;
xx=cos(2*pi*f+phi);
yy=cos(4*pi*f+phi);
zz=cos(6*pi*f+phi);

[k1] = convhull(xx,yy,zz);
trimesh(k1,xx,yy,zz)

hold on
plot3(cos(2*pi*f+phi),cos(4*pi*f+phi),cos(6*pi*f+phi),'r','linewidth',2)
```

with Jet colormap option.

You can use [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz) to get the LaTeX code and you can plot it using pgfplots package. Here is my attempt:

[image]

I've modified the Latex code:

- removed the plot of the three elements (red curve in the previous illustration)
- Changed opacity from 1 to 0.95.

Here is the LaTeX main file:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

  \input{atomicSet}

\end{document}
```

and the illustration file, named `atomicSet.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.743in,
height=2.983in,
scale only axis,
colormap/jet,
xmin=-1,
xmax=1,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
zmin=-1,
zmax=1,
view={-37.5}{30},
grid,
]
\addplot3[area legend,opacity=0.95, table/row sep=crcr, patch, shader=flat corner, fill=white, patch table with point meta={%
8   9   42  -0.998026728428272\\
8   42  75  -0.998026728428272\\
8   74  9   -0.998026728428272\\
8   75  74  -0.998026728428272\\
9   10  41  -0.992114701314478\\
9   41  42  -0.992114701314478\\
9   70  10  -0.992114701314478\\
9   71  70  -0.992114701314478\\
9   72  71  -0.992114701314478\\
9   73  72  -0.992114701314478\\
9   74  73  -0.992114701314478\\
10  11  40  -0.951056516295154\\
10  40  41  -0.951056516295154\\
10  66  11  -0.951056516295154\\
10  67  66  -0.951056516295154\\
10  68  67  -0.951056516295154\\
10  69  68  -0.951056516295154\\
10  70  69  -0.951056516295154\\
11  12  38  -0.876306680043864\\
11  38  39  -0.876306680043864\\
11  39  40  -0.876306680043864\\
11  64  12  -0.876306680043864\\
11  65  64  -0.876306680043864\\
11  66  65  -0.876306680043864\\
12  13  38  -0.770513242775789\\
12  63  13  -0.770513242775789\\
12  64  63  -0.770513242775789\\
13  14  37  -0.63742398974869\\
13  37  38  -0.63742398974869\\
13  62  14  -0.63742398974869\\
13  63  62  -0.63742398974869\\
14  15  35  -0.481753674101715\\
14  35  36  -0.481753674101715\\
14  36  37  -0.481753674101715\\
14  61  15  -0.481753674101715\\
14  62  61  -0.481753674101715\\
15  16  35  -0.309016994374948\\
15  61  16  -0.309016994374948\\
16  17  34  -0.125333233564304\\
16  34  35  -0.125333233564304\\
16  60  17  -0.125333233564304\\
16  61  60  -0.125333233564304\\
17  18  32  0.0627905195293128\\
17  32  33  0.0627905195293128\\
17  33  34  0.0627905195293128\\
17  60  18  0.0627905195293128\\
18  19  32  0.248689887164855\\
18  60  19  0.248689887164855\\
19  20  30  0.425779291565073\\
19  30  31  0.425779291565073\\
19  31  32  0.425779291565073\\
19  60  20  0.425779291565073\\
20  21  29  0.587785252292473\\
20  29  30  0.587785252292473\\
20  59  21  0.587785252292473\\
20  60  59  0.587785252292473\\
21  22  29  0.728968627421411\\
21  59  22  0.728968627421411\\
22  23  27  0.844327925502015\\
22  27  28  0.844327925502015\\
22  28  29  0.844327925502015\\
22  59  23  0.844327925502015\\
23  24  27  0.929776485888251\\
23  59  24  0.929776485888251\\
24  25  26  0.982287250728689\\
24  26  27  0.982287250728689\\
24  58  25  0.982287250728689\\
24  59  58  0.982287250728689\\
25  58  92  1\\
25  92  26  1\\
26  91  27  0.982287250728689\\
26  92  91  0.982287250728689\\
27  91  28  0.929776485888251\\
28  91  29  0.844327925502015\\
29  91  30  0.728968627421412\\
30  90  31  0.587785252292473\\
30  91  90  0.587785252292473\\
31  90  32  0.425779291565073\\
32  90  33  0.248689887164855\\
33  90  34  0.0627905195293133\\
34  89  35  -0.125333233564304\\
34  90  89  -0.125333233564304\\
35  89  36  -0.309016994374947\\
36  88  37  -0.481753674101714\\
36  89  88  -0.481753674101714\\
37  88  38  -0.637423989748689\\
38  86  39  -0.770513242775789\\
38  87  86  -0.770513242775789\\
38  88  87  -0.770513242775789\\
39  84  40  -0.876306680043863\\
39  85  84  -0.876306680043863\\
39  86  85  -0.876306680043863\\
40  80  41  -0.951056516295153\\
40  81  80  -0.951056516295153\\
40  82  81  -0.951056516295153\\
40  83  82  -0.951056516295153\\
40  84  83  -0.951056516295153\\
41  76  42  -0.992114701314478\\
41  77  76  -0.992114701314478\\
41  78  77  -0.992114701314478\\
41  79  78  -0.992114701314478\\
41  80  79  -0.992114701314478\\
42  76  75  -0.998026728428272\\
58  59  91  0.998026728428272\\
58  91  92  0.998026728428272\\
59  60  91  0.992114701314478\\
60  61  89  0.951056516295154\\
60  89  90  0.951056516295154\\
60  90  91  0.951056516295154\\
61  62  89  0.876306680043864\\
62  63  88  0.77051324277579\\
62  88  89  0.77051324277579\\
63  64  86  0.63742398974869\\
63  86  87  0.63742398974869\\
63  87  88  0.63742398974869\\
64  65  86  0.481753674101715\\
65  66  85  0.30901699437495\\
65  85  86  0.30901699437495\\
66  67  84  0.125333233564306\\
66  84  85  0.125333233564306\\
67  68  83  -0.0627905195293107\\
67  83  84  -0.0627905195293107\\
68  69  81  -0.248689887164853\\
68  81  82  -0.248689887164853\\
68  82  83  -0.248689887164853\\
69  70  80  -0.425779291565071\\
69  80  81  -0.425779291565071\\
70  71  80  -0.587785252292473\\
71  72  78  -0.72896862742141\\
71  78  79  -0.72896862742141\\
71  79  80  -0.72896862742141\\
72  73  77  -0.844327925502015\\
72  77  78  -0.844327925502015\\
73  74  77  -0.929776485888251\\
74  75  76  -0.982287250728688\\
74  76  77  -0.982287250728688\\
}]
table[row sep=crcr] {%
x   y   z\\
6.12323399573677e-17    6.12323399573677e-17    6.12323399573677e-17\\
-0.0627905195293134 -0.125333233564304  -0.187381314585725\\
-0.125333233564304  -0.248689887164855  -0.368124552684678\\
-0.187381314585725  -0.368124552684678  -0.535826794978996\\
-0.248689887164855  -0.481753674101715  -0.684547105928689\\
-0.309016994374947  -0.587785252292473  -0.809016994374947\\
-0.368124552684678  -0.684547105928689  -0.904827052466019\\
-0.425779291565073  -0.770513242775789  -0.968583161128631\\
-0.481753674101715  -0.844327925502015  -0.998026728428272\\
-0.535826794978996  -0.904827052466019  -0.992114701314478\\
-0.587785252292473  -0.951056516295154  -0.951056516295154\\
-0.63742398974869   -0.982287250728689  -0.876306680043864\\
-0.684547105928689  -0.998026728428272  -0.770513242775789\\
-0.728968627421411  -0.998026728428272  -0.63742398974869\\
-0.770513242775789  -0.982287250728689  -0.481753674101715\\
-0.809016994374947  -0.951056516295154  -0.309016994374948\\
-0.844327925502015  -0.904827052466019  -0.125333233564304\\
-0.876306680043864  -0.844327925502015  0.0627905195293128\\
-0.904827052466019  -0.770513242775789  0.248689887164855\\
-0.929776485888251  -0.684547105928689  0.425779291565073\\
-0.951056516295154  -0.587785252292473  0.587785252292473\\
-0.968583161128631  -0.481753674101716  0.728968627421411\\
-0.982287250728689  -0.368124552684678  0.844327925502015\\
-0.992114701314478  -0.248689887164855  0.929776485888251\\
-0.998026728428272  -0.125333233564305  0.982287250728689\\
-1  -1.83697019872103e-16   1\\
-0.998026728428272  0.125333233564304   0.982287250728689\\
-0.992114701314478  0.248689887164855   0.929776485888251\\
-0.982287250728689  0.368124552684678   0.844327925502015\\
-0.968583161128631  0.481753674101715   0.728968627421412\\
-0.951056516295154  0.587785252292473   0.587785252292473\\
-0.929776485888251  0.684547105928689   0.425779291565073\\
-0.904827052466019  0.770513242775789   0.248689887164855\\
-0.876306680043864  0.844327925502015   0.0627905195293133\\
-0.844327925502015  0.90482705246602    -0.125333233564304\\
-0.809016994374947  0.951056516295154   -0.309016994374947\\
-0.770513242775789  0.982287250728689   -0.481753674101714\\
-0.728968627421412  0.998026728428272   -0.637423989748689\\
-0.684547105928689  0.998026728428272   -0.770513242775789\\
-0.63742398974869   0.982287250728689   -0.876306680043863\\
-0.587785252292473  0.951056516295154   -0.951056516295153\\
-0.535826794978997  0.90482705246602    -0.992114701314478\\
-0.481753674101716  0.844327925502016   -0.998026728428272\\
-0.425779291565073  0.77051324277579    -0.968583161128631\\
-0.368124552684678  0.684547105928689   -0.90482705246602\\
-0.309016994374948  0.587785252292473   -0.809016994374948\\
-0.248689887164855  0.481753674101715   -0.684547105928689\\
-0.187381314585725  0.368124552684678   -0.535826794978996\\
-0.125333233564305  0.248689887164855   -0.368124552684678\\
-0.0627905195293132 0.125333233564305   -0.187381314585726\\
-1.83697019872103e-16   3.06161699786838e-16    -4.28626379701574e-16\\
0.0627905195293128  -0.125333233564304  0.187381314585725\\
0.125333233564304   -0.248689887164855  0.368124552684677\\
0.187381314585725   -0.368124552684677  0.535826794978997\\
0.248689887164855   -0.481753674101716  0.684547105928689\\
0.309016994374947   -0.587785252292474  0.809016994374947\\
0.368124552684678   -0.684547105928689  0.90482705246602\\
0.425779291565073   -0.770513242775789  0.968583161128631\\
0.481753674101716   -0.844327925502015  0.998026728428272\\
0.535826794978997   -0.904827052466019  0.992114701314478\\
0.587785252292473   -0.951056516295153  0.951056516295154\\
0.637423989748689   -0.982287250728689  0.876306680043864\\
0.684547105928689   -0.998026728428272  0.77051324277579\\
0.728968627421411   -0.998026728428272  0.63742398974869\\
0.770513242775789   -0.982287250728689  0.481753674101715\\
0.809016994374947   -0.951056516295154  0.30901699437495\\
0.844327925502015   -0.90482705246602   0.125333233564306\\
0.876306680043863   -0.844327925502016  -0.0627905195293107\\
0.904827052466019   -0.77051324277579   -0.248689887164853\\
0.929776485888251   -0.68454710592869   -0.425779291565071\\
0.951056516295154   -0.587785252292473  -0.587785252292473\\
0.968583161128631   -0.481753674101716  -0.72896862742141\\
0.982287250728689   -0.368124552684678  -0.844327925502015\\
0.992114701314478   -0.248689887164856  -0.929776485888251\\
0.998026728428272   -0.125333233564304  -0.982287250728688\\
1   -4.28626379701574e-16   -1\\
0.998026728428272   0.125333233564303   -0.982287250728689\\
0.992114701314478   0.248689887164855   -0.929776485888251\\
0.982287250728689   0.368124552684677   -0.844327925502015\\
0.968583161128631   0.481753674101715   -0.728968627421412\\
0.951056516295154   0.587785252292473   -0.587785252292472\\
0.929776485888251   0.684547105928689   -0.425779291565073\\
0.90482705246602    0.770513242775789   -0.248689887164856\\
0.876306680043864   0.844327925502015   -0.0627905195293155\\
0.844327925502016   0.904827052466019   0.125333233564301\\
0.809016994374948   0.951056516295153   0.309016994374947\\
0.77051324277579    0.982287250728688   0.481753674101717\\
0.728968627421412   0.998026728428272   0.637423989748688\\
0.684547105928689   0.998026728428272   0.770513242775789\\
0.63742398974869    0.982287250728689   0.876306680043865\\
0.587785252292473   0.951056516295154   0.951056516295153\\
0.535826794978996   0.904827052466019   0.992114701314478\\
0.481753674101715   0.844327925502015   0.998026728428271\\
0.425779291565073   0.77051324277579    0.968583161128632\\
0.368124552684679   0.68454710592869    0.904827052466019\\
0.309016994374948   0.587785252292474   0.80901699437495\\
0.248689887164855   0.481753674101716   0.68454710592869\\
0.187381314585725   0.368124552684678   0.535826794978996\\
0.125333233564305   0.248689887164856   0.368124552684682\\
0.0627905195293133  0.125333233564304   0.187381314585726\\
3.06161699786838e-16    5.51091059616309e-16    -9.80336419954471e-16\\
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
```